# Weierstrass approximation to a differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis

$f\colon [-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable. I need to show $\forall \epsilon >0,\  \exists$ a polynomial P s.t. $|f(x)-P(x)|\leq \epsilon|x|$.

I think I need to approximate the difference quotient $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$ with a polynomial but this isn't continuous at $0$ so I can't use Weierstrass to know that such an approximating sequence of polynomials exists.

Comment: @Davide: Did you change the $\lt$ to $\leq$ on purpose in your $\TeX$ edit?

Comment: @Davide  it was supposed to be $\leq$ so thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the definition of derivative, $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0} = f'(0)$.  So if you redefine this function at 0, you do get a continuous function.